# Compiz - making sure windows do not overlap

Tags: compiz, tiling-wm

I'm using compiz and the grid plugin with 2 24" widescreen monitors to work emulating a tiling wm workflow. I have a dark wallpaper and use lilyterm for transparency. Most of my work is entirely constrained to a terminal, but of-course I like to have a browser open often (browsers and other desktop gui apps obviously don't support transparency).

I want to make sure that only applications at the foreground are visually present in their tiling locations, and any other applications behind them don't count till they are activated.

Is this possible with compiz ? or any other workaround for it ?